# Add profile image to bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a profile image and a logout link to bootstrap side navbar.

[image: current]

This is my code so far

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <div class="img-rounded profile-img"></div>
            @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I want to center the image and the display the username below the profile image.
This is the css for `.profile-img` class

```
.profile-img {
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    background: url('../Images/profile_pic_default.png') 50% 50% no-repeat; /* 50% 50% centers image in div */
    background-size: auto 100%; /* Interchange this value depending on prefering width vs. height */
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Can some please come up with a solution for me?

Comment: you need to play around with your image "padding" in css

Answer (score 0):

```
    .profile-img, a {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .nav li {
       display: inline-block;
       vertical-align: middle;
       height: 30px;
       line-height: 30px;
    }
```

height and line-height value optional.